# Excel graphing and axis

Tags: excel

I have a scatterplot with values that range from 2 to -2.  The catch is that 1 is the "zero-point".  In other words the minimum positive value is 1.01 and the minimum negative value is -1.01.  How can I edit the axis of the graph so that 0 is replaced with 1.

Comment: It's easy to replace 0 with 1 using a custom number format for the axis. However, I'm not entirely sure what your data looks like from your description, nor do I know whether you're in need of changing other elements on the (horizontal/category?) axis. Perhaps you can describe the problem some more with a set of data points.

Comment: Let's say I have y-axis points at 1.01, 1.05, 1.4, 2.0, -1.05, -1.40, -1.65, -2.0.  X-axis points are irrelevant.  All I need is a scatterplot with a y-axis starting at 1 and going to 2 and -2.  In other words, I simply want to replace 0 with 1.

Comment: If you *only* have y-axis labels at -2, 0 and 2, then you can change these to -2, 1 and 2. If you have y-axis labels at -2, -1, 0, 1 and 2, then I'm not sure whether you can do it that easily...

Comment: Did you find anything posted useful? Please post feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of Excel later than 2007 I'd suggest splitting the positives and negatives into separate series and plotting one on a secondary axis (not that I know whether or not that would work!), but with 2007 I have not been able to place one vertical axis above the horizontal and another below. Instead the best I could manage was to use two separate charts:

[image: SO18118071 example]

by again splitting up the series, careful positioning and judicious use of a text box for `0`.

At least this way you are not constrained by the outer limits.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some very specific conditions you can print the zero-point as 1 using a custom number format: You have to set the axis options to be fixed at -2 (minimum) and 2 (maximum) with a major unit of 2 as well. This ensure that you only have the three values -2, 0 and 2 on the vertical/y-axis. Why is this important? Well, custom number formats can easily distinguish between positive/negative and zero values which is exactly what you have when you have -2, 0 and 2.

Here's a visual of the input/output:

[image]

The [custom number format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) is set to `2;-2;1`, thereby formatting all *positive* numbers to `2`, all *negative* numbers to `-2` and *zero* to `1`.

Comment: You may wish to scale your output to also reflect the 1 zero-point. That is, multiply every y-value by `0.5`.

Comment: I don't want to limit myself to between -2 and 2.  How do I number from 1 to any positive or negative integer with increments of 1? If I can't do any number, how about a max of 6 and -6 with increments of 1?

Comment: @JohnSmith: It's not going to be easy. As I mentioned, you need a very particular situation for this to work out-of-the-box. Alternatively, you could use the minor units to insert ticks *without* a label, and then insert them manually using text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to replace the axis label "0" with "1" (as in the answer by Werner), then you can use the following (similar to [this](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ScientificNotation.html)):

1. Add X and Y values for a dummy series, with 3 points. If the minimum value  in your X-axis is xm, your points are (xm, -2), (xm, 0), (xm, 2).
2. Add cells with the 3 labels that you will use for the dummy series: "-2", "1", "2".
3. Go to the chart, and remove the tick labels of the Y-axis.
4. Add a series with the 3 dummy data points.
5. Add the labels to the data points. You can use references to the cells of item 2, or enter explicit labels. Entering each label (either a reference or an explicit label) is tedious when you have many data points. Check [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/05/05/change-data-labels-in-charts/), and in particular [Rob Bovey´s add-in](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm). It is excellent.
6. Format the dummy series so it is visually ok (e.g., small, hairline crosses, no line).

You can use variations on this. For instance, you can add extra points to your dummy series, with corresponding labels. Gridlines would match the dummy series.

But **I think this is not appropriate**, as the locations of your data points will be inconsistent with the scales.

What is appropriate is having an *interrupted axis*, where the interval (-1,1) is eliminated.
The answer by pnuts aims at that.
I propose something different, with the advantage of **using only one chart**:

1. Create a column where you add 2, only to negative Y-values. Use that column as your new Y-values.
2. Use the same trick as above, with your dummy series now being (xm, 0), (xm, 1), (xm, 2), and the labels the same as above.

You can use additional points in your dummy series.

You can use this technique to create an arbitrary number of axis interruptions. The formula for the "fake" Y-values would be more complicated, with `IF`s to detect the interval corresponding to each point, and suitable linear transformations to account for the change in scale for each interval (assuming linear scales; no mixing linear-log). But that is all.

PS: see also the links below. I still think my alternative is better.

http://peltiertech.com/broken-y-axis-in-excel-chart/

http://ksrowell.com/blog-visualizing-data/2013/08/12/how-to-simulate-a-broken-axis-value-axis/

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/broken_y_axis/tutorial/index.html#Rescale%20and%20hide%20the%20y-axis